# Loading dialog size does not update correctly on Android 4.0.2/WebKit 534.30

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to display two loading dialogs in succession, calling one after the other.

The problem is that the second dialog retains the dimensions of the first one, so its contents do not fit.

It can be reproduced with the default browser in Android version 4.0.2 : AppleWebKit/534.30. Other browsers do not seem to have this problem. Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/loader.html
2. Click "Default loader"
3. Click "Text only"
4. Second loading message is not fully visible. Example:

   [image]
5. If I click somewhere after that, the size is corrected.

   [image]

What could be causing this? How could I get the second dialog to be shown with correct size in this browser? Thank You.